# Saving multiple Console.ReadLine() inputs without creating a text file?

Tags: c#, console-application

This code below works and I can type in the console and then Insert() my product into a temporary "list". I can easily create a text file output and just use that to load all my items but I am trying to get it done without needing that.

But every time I finish typing in the info, location and amount and then press "n", I can't get every entry of mine to print, only the most recent. I'd like to keep being able to press "y" to restart the inputs and keep adding new lines of products until I say "n", where only then will every product I typed in display to me at the top of the console-app whilst its running.

```
public void FirstCategory()
        {
            string info;
            string location;
            int amount; 

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Temp Products");
            Console.WriteLine("To enter a product, enter the info, location, and amount.");

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the product info: ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the product location: ");
            description = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the available amount: ");
            stock = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Products aProduct = new Products();

            aProduct.Insert(info, location, amount);

            aProduct.Display();
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Do you wish to enter another product? ");
            Console.WriteLine("y/n");
            string answer = Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToLower();
            if (answer == "y")
            {
                FirstCategory();
            }
            else if (answer == "n")
            {
                // Display all list items inputted by user
            }

        }
```

I have much more code that I can't show here but essentially it allows for me to have up to [6] categories and inserts products into an already existing list.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** I didnt read properly i saw you have an insert method in your Products.cs well you cant display anything anyway because you creating a new Products object everytime so the previous inserted informations are lost and only the last input can get displayed in the else-if-statement. Alternativ would be to **instantiate** the **Products** class **outside** the **method** then you **dont** need the **list**.

Outside of the Method create a List with Products.

```
List<Products> myProductList = new List<Products>();
```

You add all Products to the list an after typing "n" you will list these products. In your example you cant list all products because you are not saving them somehow, you just create object after object. And you only have

```
  FirstCategory() {
...
    Products aProduct = new Products();
    
    myProductList.Add(aProduct); // add the product to the list
    else if (answer == "n") {
        foreach(Products myProd in myProductList) {
            Console.WriteLine(myProd.Display()); // define method which returns string
            // or just write the variables in console
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {myProd.name} \nStock: {myProd.stock}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What are ValueA & B supposed to be, and also the printMethod?

Comment: @askinuni64 you're welcome, i updated my answer hope its a little clearer. myProd.printMethod() is maybe the same what you defined in the method .Display() i replaced it. Inside from display since you write everything to console, there should be a Console.WriteLine function which returns the properties of the current object like stock name and so on.

Comment: @askinuni64 if a user has answered your question and you are satisfied with it then please set the green check mark as done.